# Security and .htaccess

Tags: plugins, security, htaccess

About a month ago I started a WordPress blog on a hosted server related to a hobby. So, I am new to this at present.

Since I'm concerned about security, one thing I did was to install the plugin WP Security Scan. According to the plugin results, my site checks out except that I get this in the results as a red flag:

> The file .htaccess does not exist in wp-admin/ (I ssh'd in there and it does not exist)

Ok, so I did a considerable search on the issue and find too much info on .htaccess. I've been through Hardening WordPress on the WordPress.org site, etc. And also ran into this article: http://digwp.com/2010/07/wordpress-security-lockdown/

Anyway, I've basically gotten confused with the plethora of information available.

**What should the .htaccess file in wp-admin contain?** I've read that this .htaccess file should password protect the wp-admin directory and I've also read that this can cause functionality problems.

Help with this is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.
-wdypdx22

**Update** Ok, so I'm not logged in to my blog and using a different computer than usual. I enter the url www.mysite.com/wordpress/wp-admin/ and there is a redirect to login. If that's what happens, then is an htaccess file even needed in the wp-admin directory?

Comment: Have you tried asking the developer of WP Security Scan?

Comment: @Doug - Yes, the developer has a forum with at least 2 other people asking the exact same question and no response. Also, I posted on wordpress.org and no response there either. So, maybe this doesn't even matter?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***UPDATE***: When I first posted my answer I missed the crux of the question; my answer was about `.htaccess` security in general and is now listed below the double line (look down if it interests you.) Unfortunately I don't have specific experience with securing `/wp-admin/` using `.htaccess` so I'll simply list the two resources I will pursue when and if I need it:

- [Hardening WordPress with .htaccess](http://blogsecurity.net/wordpress/article-210607)
- [AskApache Password Protection, For WordPress](http://www.askapache.com/wordpress/htaccess-password-protect.html#comment)

The first one recommends the following (and here is [some discussion about it](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/codes-for-htaccess-in-wp-admin).)

```
<Files ~ "\.(php)$">
AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/htpasswd
AuthType Basic
AuthName "restricted"
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Require valid-user
Satisfy any
</Files>
```

The latter has lots of information, especially in the comments, but admittedly providing you a list to read is not the answer you were looking for.

Sorry I couldn't have been more helpful on this one.

========================================

Typically WordPress only has the following which handled permalink processing and is not related to security:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Recently I've found the [WP htacess Control](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-htaccess-control/) plugin that manages a lot of `.htaccess` for you and I rather like it a lot.  After tweaking it's settings it added the following options:

```
# WPhtC: Disable ServerSignature on generated error pages
ServerSignature Off

# WPhtC: Disable directory browsing
Options All -Indexes

# WPhtC: Protect WP-config.php
<files wp-config.php>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>

# WPhtC: Protect .htaccess file
<files ~ "^.*\.([Hh][Tt][Aa])">
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>
```

It also added these options which are about performance instead of security:

```
# WPhtC: Setting mod_gzip
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file \.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>

# WPhtC: Setting mod_deflate
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml application/xml application/xhtml+xml text/javascript text/css application/x-javascript
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
</IfModule>
```

Beyond this one there are some plugins I haven't tried but that are focused on security and that interact with `.htaccess` - you might try them each just to see what they do to the `.htaccess` file:

- [WP Super Secure and Fast htaccess](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-super-secure-and-fast-htaccess/) ([also](http://www.andreapernici.com/wordpress/wp-super-secure-and-fast-htaccess/))
- [BulletProof Security](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/bulletproof-security/)
- [Silence is Golden Guard](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/silence-is-golden-guard/)
- [WP-BlockYou](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-blockyou/)
- [Stealth Login](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/stealth-login/screenshots/)
- [HTTP Authentication](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/http-authentication/)
- [AskApache Password Protect](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/askapache-password-protect/)

Beyond that, if you want to know the (IMO) #1 expert resource on [Apache security related to WordPress](http://www.askapache.com/search/wordpress+security/) you can find it on [AskApache.com](http://www.askapache.com/); dude is hardcore! His blog won't solve your "*too much information*" problem but at least you can view it as an authoritative resource!

Here are some examples (though not all are directly WordPress related they all are applicable):

- [Advanced WordPress wp-config.php Tweaks](http://www.askapache.com/wordpress/advanced-wp-config-php-tweaks.html)
- [Example .htaccess for WordPress](http://www.askapache.com/security/wordpress-plugin-for-apache-htaccess-security.html#menu0-el1)
- [Advanced WordPress 404](http://www.askapache.com/wordpress/wordpress-404.html)
- [Mod_Security .htaccess tricks](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/mod_security-htaccess-tricks.html)
- [.htaccess Plugin Blocks Spam, Hackers, and Password Protects Blog](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/htaccess-plugin-blocks-spam-hackers-and-password-protects-blog.html)

Anyway, hope this helps.

Comment: Great Information for overall security, but doesn't answer about /wp-admin/ folder

Comment: While this may all be useful information, none of it has anything to do with the question. This all relates to .htaccess in the root directory. The original question was about .htaccess in the wp-admin subdirectory.

Comment: @Insanity5902 @Doug: My bad. I just didn't see that when I was reading it.

Comment: I accepted your answer basically because, bottom line, overall security is my goal. My blog is very new, but my traffic is growing. Basically, I just want security measures in place for if and when I actually start getting lots of traffic. -Thanks

Comment: @wdypdx - Big thanks. I was really embarrassed when I realized I had missed your core question in bold. Glad it turned out positive.

Answer (score 5):

The idea behind it, if you have strangling files hanging behind from past upgrades or for zero-day attacks, your system could be hacked. Also securing the wp-admin by another method will help against brute-force attacks.

One Idea) If it is just you editing the site you can limit access to the folder by ip doing something like

```
<Files *>
Order deny,allow
Deny from All
Allow from 1.2.3.4
</Files>
```

To make it a bit more tolerable for dynamic IP systems; you should be able to allow from a subblock, so if you IP pool is always from 1.2.3.128 - 1.2.3.255, then you could do something like 1.2.3.128/25

Another Idea) require HTTPS, give a permissioned denied if they try it over http. But don't redirect them to the https. You can use a self-signed cert or one from CA Cert to get by without buying one.

Answer (score 0):

I always include a .htaccess file in wp-admin, even if I never put anything in it, since it negates the root directory's file. Some people use the wp-admin .htaccess file to hide the whole directory from all but one IP address, others use it to password protect the directory.

However, password protecting the admin section with .htaccess will disable ajax communications, since they interact with wp-admin/admin-ajax.php.

Generally, I don't see much reason to add anything to the admin .htaccess file unless you're extremely paranoid. Attacks usually target wp-content anyway.

Comment: An .htaccess file in a subdirectory can override directives in the root directory, but a blank .htaccess does not negate anything.

Comment: Then I have been misinformed. Hmmmm...

Comment: What you need to do is reverse what is in the root, if anything. However, Insanity's answer is better than the one marked as the best, though it would be best if it had Insanity's info in it.

Answer (score 0):

i use also the library sseqlib for more security and different hacks in the .htacces; see the links

- [sseq-lib](http://www.erich-kachel.de/?page_id=133)
- [.htaccess example](http://code.google.com/p/wp-basis-theme/source/browse/trunk/basis/wp-root-tipps/.htaccess)